# Find valid object from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have the following array in my javascript code:

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'test@user.com',
    password: 'password',
    access_token: 'test_user_access_token'
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    email: 'second@user.com',
    password: 'password',
    access_token: 'second_user_access_token'
  }
]
```

From this collection I want to retrieve user by email. So for example I will write:

`my_function("test@user.com")` it will return this one user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what the [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method is for.

```js
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'test@user.com',
    password: 'password',
    access_token: 'test_user_access_token'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: 'second@user.com',
    password: 'password',
    access_token: 'second_user_access_token'
  }
];

console.log(users.find(u => u.email == 'test@user.com'));
```

So `.find()` is called on the array, and receives a callback function. The callback will be invoked for each item in the array, for which you return the result of comparing the `.email` property to the email you're looking for.

As soon as your callback returns a `true` (or truthy) result, the iteration halts, and returns that object from `.find()`. If no is found, `.find()` returns `undefined`.

---

Note that this uses arrow function syntax. If you prefer, you can use traditional functions.

```
console.log(users.find(function(u) { return u.email == 'test@user.com' }));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Array#find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function. Pass a predicate into the function, which will return the first matched item based on that predicate.

```js
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: 'test@user.com',
    password: 'password',
    access_token: 'test_user_access_token'
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    email: 'second@user.com',
    password: 'password',
    access_token: 'second_user_access_token'
  }
]

function findByEmail(email) {
  return users.find(x => x.email === email);
}

console.log(findByEmail('test@user.com'));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always the good old fashioned for-loop:

```js
const users = [{
    id: 1,
    email: 'test@user.com',
    password: 'password',
    access_token: 'test_user_access_token'
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    email: 'second@user.com',
    password: 'password',
    access_token: 'second_user_access_token'
  }
]

function findUserByEmail(userList, desiredEmailAddress) {
  for (let i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
    var user = userList[i];
    if (user.email === desiredEmailAddress) {
      return user;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

var desiredUser = findUserByEmail(users, 'second@user.com');
if (desiredUser) {
  console.log('User found by email:\n');
  console.log(desiredUser);
} else {
  console.log('No user found with searched email address');
}
```